# Create Python Web Service

Tags: python, web-services, soap

I have a module I created to generate Javascript for inputs on the server side. I'd like to expose this as a SOAP web service so other languages can use it as well. I searched the internet but everything I find relates to creating a SOAP consumption client and doesn't cover building the actual web services.

Please advise...

Thanks!
Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Comment: Might something like this help: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/979/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [soaplib](https://github.com/soaplib/soaplib):

> This is a simple, easily extendible soap library that provides several useful tools for creating, publishing and consuming soap web services in python.

Also see the [documentation](http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/).